Upgrade/patch the Linux Kernel version without compiling everything
I downloaded & compiled 6.9.5 version from kernel.org.
Is it possible to compile/patch directly from 6.9.5 to the last 6.10.3?

In theory, it could be possible to start with a kernel version, and then apply the incremental (source code) patches to get to the more recent version. Make would then only recompile the modified files. Problem is your confidence level in downloading all of the necessary individual patches needed and correctly applying them in the correct order, versus downloading a new, single tarball of source code. IOW it's a tradeoff of a lot of manual work versus a longer buildtime. You may not save any time at all.
